# Is it possible, and/or advisable to develop Django web applications on OS X (10.6.4 and 10.5.8) using Python 2.6.5 64-bit? Why?

Tags: python, django, 64-bit, x86-64, python-2.6

I'm trying to decide on which architecture to choose for developing Django 1.0.x through Django 1.2.1. I've managed to get MySQL, MySQLdb, PIL, and Python 2.65 installed on Snow Leopard using x86 64-bit builds, but I'm curious as to whether or not there is a definitive answer to this question at the moment, and if so, why?

Thank you!
Michaux

Comment: Many months later I blogged my own solution to this concern:

http://webamused.wordpress.com/2011/01/31/building-64-bit-python-python-org-using-ucs-4-on-mac-os-x-10-6-6-snow-leopard/

Now my Mac is my main work computer. I haven't encountered issues thus far, and I just so happened to notice a staggering number of users at PyCon 2010 using Macs too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it's possible. Advisable? You didn't mention httpd and mod_wsgi, or some other WSGI container. Get one installed and it should be fine.

Comment: Thanks Ignacio, I just needed a vote of confidence from a more experienced developer such as yourself before "going down the rabbit hole". And so my journey continues! No problems so far ;) Thank you very much.

Comment: the rabbit hole has been good to me! I didn't even need mod_wsgi to do normal Python and Django development, but thanks to your suggestion I now know much more!

Answer (score 1):

It certainly is possible: I do it every day.

Some tips:

- use virtualenv to sandbox your python packages between projects.
- use mod_passenger (via Passenger.prefpane) to make VirtualHosts easier to deal with.

You may need to fiddle a bit harder with things if you run stuff under mod_python, as I recall having to work hard to get a version compiled that worked with the version of apache that is installed by default, and the python I was using.

Comment: @matthew-schinckel: your suggestions worked out most excellently! **virutalenv** and **virtualenvwrapper**? I rarely leave home without them now! I never got around to using mod_passenger, but now that I've revisited this question I just might! You might also enjoy the link I added to the comments in my original question. Thanks again :)